# Using async task in a baseadapter to load listview of file thumbnails

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am trying to load a list of picture files from my devices storage to a list view a user can interact with.  I am currently using a view holder pattern to clean up the scrolling but it seems like this isn't enough because the more pictures in the list, the choppier the scrolling gets.  I've looked into using Async task but I'm not familiar with using it to populate a list view of thumbnails involving a baseadapter.

These are the kind of objects I have in my listview.  Each item is a "Selfie" object that is defined in another class.

[image]

Here is my getView from the BaseAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.v(TAG, "in getView for position " + position +
            ", convertView is " +
            ((convertView == null)?"null":"being recycled"));

    View newView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (null == convertView) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.description = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.picture = (ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        newView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) newView.getTag();
    }

    holder.picture.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    SelfieObject selfie = (SelfieObject) getItem(position);
    setPic(holder.picture, new Point(WIDTH, HEIGHT), selfie.getPath());

    TextView textView = (TextView) holder.description;
    textView.setText(selfie.getName());


    return newView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    ImageView picture;
    TextView description;
```

Here is the async code I am looking to use from the Developers site:

```
new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
private ViewHolder v;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
    v = params[0];
    return mFakeImageLoader.getImage();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (v.position == position) {
        // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
        // progress and set and show the image
        v.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        v.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        v.icon.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
  }
}.execute(holder);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can implement this in the BaseAdapter?  The Android Dev code seems too generic for what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should EXTEND the AsyncTask class, e.g.:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
    }

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a better practice to use a seperate class you say?  I see.  I understand that this code you provided is just an example but how do I use AsyncTask to interact with loading a bitmap or imageview?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not a better practice - it is a must! AsyncTask is an abstract class - meaning that it cannot be used as itself without extending to another class. Back to your question: You can load your image in your "doInBackground" class, and return the value as a Bitmap. Then use the Bitmap in your ImageView like the example I just put up there.

Comment: If you really need a step-by-step tutorial, you can follow this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html